# Creating a MySQL view using the COUNT aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, function, count

I'm creating a standard `COUNT` query with a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT
    t2.column3                  ,
    t1.id AS t1_id              ,
    t2.column4                  ,
    COUNT ( t3.id ) AS t3_count , -- Error here
    COUNT ( t4.id ) AS t4_count
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.column1 = 25 AND
                       t2.column2 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.column1 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.column1 = t1.id
GROUP BY t2.column3 ,
         t1.id      ,
         t2.column4 ;
```

But this gives an error:

```
Error Code: 1630. FUNCTION mydb.COUNT does not exist.
```

Why does MySQL think I'm trying to invoke a user-defined-function in my database?
Does it not recognize `COUNT` as a built-in aggregate operation?

I also tried `COUNT ( t3.* )` but that gave a generic syntax error.
I can't use `COUNT ( * )` because there are multiple `LEFT JOINS` being counted at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove spaces:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT
    t2.column3                  ,
    t1.id AS t1_id              ,
    t2.column4                  ,
    COUNT(t3.id) AS t3_count , -- Error here
    COUNT(t4.id) AS t4_count
FROM      table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.column1 = 25 AND
                       t2.column2 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.column1 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.column1 = t1.id
GROUP BY t2.column3 ,
         t1.id      ,
         t2.column4 ;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01d15ce98244e925c9a4064a534fa169)**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
-- 1

SELECT COUNT (*)
-- You have an error in your SQL syntax; 

SELECT COUNT ( * )
-- You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

---

## Addendum:

As [@Paul Spiegel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563083/paul-spiegel) commented this behaviour could be altered:

```
set session sql_mode = concat(@@sql_mode, ',IGNORE_SPACE');

SELECT COUNT ( * )
-- 1
```

[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26936b422a713bf6798eb82f35d6f7ad)

Comment: @Giffyguy This behavior is configurable. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26936b422a713bf6798eb82f35d6f7ad)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you very much for that! Good to know. I'll have to look into the array of configurable options available, and see what else is there.